# Z-index issues - How to bring a child element onto the parent's below element?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm in trouble with a z-index issue. How can I bring the `DIV C` to the foreground? I mean, how can I put the `DIV C` in front of the the `DIV B`?

Is there a way to do it and keep the same z-index for `DIV A` and `DIV B` (Without decrease the z-index of the "DIV B")?

[image]
**HTML**

```
<div class="a">
  DIV A
  <div class="c">DIV C</div>
</div>

<div class="b">DIV B</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.a,
.b {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.a { background-color: #2196F3; }
.b { background-color: rgba(156, 39, 176, .9); }

.c {
  background-color: #FFC107;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

This example is here: http://codepen.io/willianribeiro/pen/LpoNJg?editors=110

Comment: add a lower `z-index` to `.c`, meaning 9 or less

Comment: My conclusion was that theres no way to do it according the conditions that I mentioned. So I think the solution more suitable to me was treat the z-index of the elements independently. Thank you everbody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since c is nested in a, its z-index is going to be compared to other elements nested in div a. If c is in a and b and a have the same z-index, I don't think you can put c in front of b. I would just consider restructuring your html

Comment: Thank you, your answer help me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.a, .b {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 8px;

}

.a { background-color: #2196F3; z-index: 10; }
.b { background-color: rgba(156, 39, 176, .9); }

.c {
  background-color: #FFC107;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  DIV A
  <div class="c">DIV C</div>
</div>

<div class="b">DIV B</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think theres no way to do it exactly according the conditions that I mentioned, so this is the best way to do.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `a` is a parent of `c`, you would need to bring `a` above `b`, which would in turn bring `c` above `b`.

If you want to treat each of them fully independently, your html must be restructured so that `c` is not a child of `a`.

Comment: Thank you, your answer help a lot as well.

Answer (score -1):

You needed to set the z-index for .c and .b

```css
   

 .a, .b {
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.a {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}
.b {
    background-color: rgba(156, 39, 176, .9);
    z-index:1;
}
.c {
    background-color: #FFC107;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
  

<div class="a">DIV A
    <div class="c">DIV C</div>
</div>
<div class="b">DIV B</div>
```

Comment: *Is there a way to do it and keep the same z-index for "DIV A" and "DIV B"*

Comment: Thank you for answer, but how LcSalazar mentioned, I needed that `DIV A` and `DIV B` had the same z-index.